# Multidimensional array and pointer to pointer value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Given the following:

```
int ar2[3][2];
int * pt;
int **p2;
p2 = &pt;
*p2 = ar2[0];
```

This is what my book says:

> *p2 is type pointer-to-int, making it compatible with ar2[0].
>   *Recall that ar2[0] **is a pointer** to its first element*, art2[0][0], making ar2[0] type pointer-to-int also.

Is it everything true?

Comment: The book is simplifying matters. `ar2[0]` is the first element of `ar2[3][2]` which is a 2-dimensional array; 2-dmensional arrays in C are arrays of 1-dimensional arrays though, so that the first element is a 1-dimensional array. You can easily check that by checking its size with `sizeof(ar2[0])`. Now in assignments and parameter passing arrays in C decay or are "adjusted" to pointers, so that the statement `*p2 = ar2[0];` is possible, but `ar2[0]` itself is not a pointer.

Comment: This is my answer, thank you @PeterA.Schneider

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider You should make that an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a pointer**

A 4/8 byte sized entity, variable or constant (`type * p` or `type const * p`), that must specify the type of the entities to which they point to. If variable it can change the entity to which it points to.

**What is an array**

An array always exists on stack, its memory size equals the count of its elements times the size of their type, and like const pointers, it can't stop pointing to its defining elements. A Multidimensional array can be seen as a tree of arrays: specifiying a position in its 0th dimension will return another with one less dimension.

**Answer**

In practice, arrays can work as specialized stack const pointers that point to the first element one level below in the hierarchy:

1. `type {*}` for `type {*} arr[]`
2. `type {*} arr[]` for `type {*} arr2[][]`
3. `type {*} arr2[][]` for `type {*} arr3[][][]`
4. `Element 0 of 0th dimension` for `Any array`

That is why `arp` in `int (* arp)[2] = ar2` would be a pointer to the array `ar2[0]` (i.e. the first branch of `ar2`).

**They are not pointers**, but I believe this way of thinking improves the model one internally has of the language.

Comment: This is incorrect. As mentioned in the question comments, `arr2[0]` is an *array of 2 `int`s, not a pointer-to-`int`*. It will *decay* to a pointer, which is why the assignment works, but it is itself an array.

Comment: I have just improved my interpretation of arrays. I think it makes clear I do not think arr2[0] is a pointer.